# Microservices: Data sharing vs API composition

Tags: microservices

to give you a bit of context, I'm developing a game, an online soccer manager, and I have the following microservices:

- Clubs
- Season

The `Clubs` microservice takes care of the club management and the `Season` is responsible for the Season management.

One of the responsibilities of the `Season` service is return the league standings, with the club names and their positions. In the `Season` service, I only store the `club_id`, but to fulfill the request to return the standings, I would need also the club name, which resides in the `Clubs` service.

Now, I could implement a REST endpoint in the `Clubs` service to return the club name, but them those service won't be loosely coupled anymore.

As I saw from my readings, I have 2 options, and they are:

- Have a `clubs` cache in the `Season` service, where it does the relationship between the `club_id` and `club_name` (Could be a database table). In this case the data will be duplicated  (which is OK for most of the cases), but I need to keep in sync with the domain events dispatched by the `Clubs` Service.
- The other option would be create another microservice to be used as API composition pattern. So this API would get data from both service, enrich the response and send back to the caller.

Now, I'm in doubt which approach should be taken. Which one has less downsides?

Answer (score 1):

Both are described in [Saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html). There are pros and cons of both. You have to choose based on your NFRs.